# Parent directories name combined with the new directory name

Tags: java, macos, file, directory, filenames

When i create a directory in my program the directory name will not be the one i wanted. The directory gets created in the right place but the name of it is combined with the parent directory.

```
String folderPath = album.toString();
folderPath = filePath+" "+folderPath;
File folder = new File(folderPath);
System.out.println(filePath);
folder.mkdir();
```

Here filePath is "/Users/Myname/Desktop/Skrivbord" and folderPath is "All Photos".

The directory is created but its named "Skrivbord All Photos". I can't figure out how to get the directory to be named just "All Photos".

I'm on a Mac if that's of any help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's the java file chooser that sets the name of the parent directory in the new directory name. In the "file" field it says "Skrivbord". Guess I have to check if some settings in the file chooser have to be made.

But hey, thanks for the tips guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
folderPath = filePath+" "+folderPath;
```

to this:

```
folderPath = filePath+"/"+folderPath;
```

Edit based on comment:

If you need to also create the parent directories, you can use `folder.mkdirs()` and it will create necessary parent directories as well.

Comment: Does the folder "Skrivbord" exist? If not, change `mkdir()` to `mkdirs()` and it will create the parent directories for you too.

Comment: Yes it does exsist, at least i think so. I get the filePath from the Java file chooser. And btw "Skrivbord" is "Desktop" in swedish so the folder is there, but I can try with mkdirs() instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the NIO.2 File API:

```
Path parentDirPath = Paths.get(parentDirPathString)
Path albumPath = parentDirPath.resolve(album.toString());
System.out.println(albumPath);
Files.createDirectories(albumPath);
```

Comment: Is this some API I have to download from somewhere or is it built in to java?

Comment: edit: Okay so it's in JDK 7. I really don't if I can install that because this program is for a project course in school and I don't know if it will work then on their computers.

Comment: Please note that Oracle Java SE 6 reached End of Life. I recommend that your school at least updates to the latest Java SE 7 version or better to the latest Java SE 8 version. Maybe they did that already, so you just might want to check that first.

Comment: Yeah I have to check with them and see which version they'r running.